# How to download file with puppeteer if page doesn't send any request

Tags: browser, frontend, bots, puppeteer, client-side

I'm using puppeteer for downloading a file from the site. I have only an element which I click and file just downloads.
I googled info about downloading files with puppeteer but all of them are based on `page.on('request', ...)`. But it doesn't work for me because page doesn't send any request

```
page.on('request', arg => {
  console.log(arg.url())
})
```

And in the terminal I have only "https://some-site/images/csv.gif" but it's only .gif. How does this file downloads at all? If browser doesn't do any request does it mean that this file is already on the client site?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try (replace the variables on top fit to your needs):

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const url = 'your.url.com';
const buttonElementId = '#downloadButton';
   
(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(url);
    await page.click(buttonElementId);
    await browser.close();
})();
```

Comment: Thank you, I understand a little how to work with puppeteer. I've wrote a few bots which log in to sites and download files. But I always used an approach with `page.on('request'` where I handle the request, stop it, send request with my cookies and result I save to some file. But for exactly this site this approach doesn't work. There is not request sent. Even when I open dev tools -> network tab and click on button "download" I don't see any request made by browser to server. File just downloads to my computer.

Comment: The URL is a target to download a file?

Comment: don't understand you

Comment: Can you provide the URL?

Comment: I've added an image. Can't give an url, sorry, there is a private data

Comment: Maybe these files are not downloaded at all, but GENERATED by javascript in the browser? Do you know if it's possible to handle downloading of generated files? (I need file stream or file buffer)

Comment: The file is getting download in the moment you enter the URL. I get it now. Take a look at https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/1478